# Can't login to Meta Mathematics SE

Tags: support, login

Every time I try to login to [Meta Math SE](https://meta.math.stackexchange.com), if I click the “login” button in the top bar, I am immideately returned to the page I came from without being logged in.

I also have tried to sign up, but the same thing happens - after I click the “Sign up using Google” button, I am returned to the page I was on before.

Comment: The URL you linked is using https, are you using some extension like HTTPSanywhere to force SSL? That can break SE sites

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Yes, after disabling HTTPS Everywhere, it works. Thanks.